# How to properly clone a branch in a DOM structure using Javascript and removing the last node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clone

I have two divs, one for left side and one for right side.
On the left one I appended 5 different images. I need to clone those 5 to the right one, append them to the right one and delete the last node.

**For the left one:**

```
var LS = document.getElementById("left");

var number = 5;
while(number > 0)
{
    var theImage = document.createElement("img");
    LS.appendChild(theImage);
    number--;
}
```

**For the right side:**

```
var RS = document.getElementById("right");
var leftImages = LS.cloneNode(true);

RS.appendChild(leftImages);

while(RS.lastChild!=null)
{
    var noviCh = RS.lastChild;
}
RS.removeChild(noviCh);
```

Code doesn't work. Anyone has idea why?

Comment: "doesn't work" ? pls be more specific about what error/behavior is occurring.

Comment: Your ´while` loop in the right side code might not terminate, as the condition does not change in the body

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding all the images and then removing one, how about just not adding the last one in the first place?

```js
var LS = document.getElementById("left");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  var theImage = document.createElement("img");
  LS.appendChild(theImage);
}

var RS = document.getElementById("right");
var imgs = LS.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length - 1; i += 1) {
  RS.appendChild(imgs[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
#left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#right {
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var LS = document.getElementById("left");

for ( var number = 5; number > 0; number--)
{
    LS.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
}
```

and

```
var RS = document.getElementById("right");

while( LS.lastChild )
{
    RS.appendChild( LS.lastChild.cloneNode(true) );
    LS.removeChild( LS.lastChild );
}
```